# Flutter : Object as an element of listview

Tags: flutter, listview

This is a widget which is essentially a widget with an icon and a text :

```
class Record extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RecordState createState() => _RecordState();
}

class _RecordState extends State<Record> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.cyanAccent,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget> [
          Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward_ios_sharp,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          Text(
            "Hello"
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I use this widget to generate a list of such objects :

```
List<Record> getRecordElements(){
    var items = List<Record>.generate(1000, (index) => null);
    return items;
  }
  Widget getRecordView(){
    var listItems = getRecordElements();
    var listview = ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return ListTile(
            leading: listItems[index],
          );
        }
    );
    return listview;
}
```

But my list is totally blank. Please help

Answer (score 0):

let's try:

```
 List<Record> getRecordElements() {
   var items = List<Record>.generate(1000, (index) => index);
   return items;
 }

 Widget getRecordView() {
   var listItems = getRecordElements();
   var listview = ListView.builder(
     itemCount: listItems.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       return ListTile(
         leading: Text("....."),
        );
      });
  }
```

ex: ListView.builder: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Comment: Thank you but I want to pass widgets of the class Record, and not text